# Ubuntu 22.04 LTS, installing build-dep and linux crashes wayland

Tags: ubuntu, apt, wayland

I'm hoping to get some help.

I'm trying to setup my system to compile a realtime kernel.

On a freshly installed Ubuntu 22.04 the things I'm doing:

Select sources in Ubuntu Software Installation GUI.

Then:

```
apt update && apt upgrade
apt-get build-dep linux
```

As soon as the installation finishes Wayland crashes, wifi crashes and as soon as I reboot or logout I cannot start Wayland again. I also cannot restart the wifi connection.

I'm not quite sure how this can happen and hoping for some help.

Comment: I can't find a package named `linux` in the Ubuntu repositories.  Does the package you're installing have a slightly different name, like `linux-aws` or something?

Comment: I used a [guide](http://docs.ros.org.ros.informatik.uni-freiburg.de/en/foxy/Tutorials/Miscellaneous/Building-Realtime-rt_preempt-kernel-for-ROS-2.html), since i'm not an expert at kernel stuff.

The commands above, are the commands i've put in the terminal. It shouldn't crash my system if the package name is wrong, should it?

Answer (score 0):

I read the guide and there's more going on than mentioned in the question.  The guide is about getting the kernel source code and compiling a real-time kernel for your machine.  The `linux` package I didn't recognize is the kernel source code.

The guide doesn't actually ask you to perform `apt update && apt upgrade` after selecting "sources" in the GUI.  The next command it shows is `sudo apt-get build-dep linux`.  And then install a list of other packages.  I believe selecting "sources" in the GUI before the update and upgrade might be causing this.

Here is my advice:

If you want to perform the update & upgrade commands, go ahead, but don't do it in the middle of this guide's steps.  Do it before you start the guide:

1. Do a clean install of Ubuntu 22.04
2. Perform your update & upgrade command: `apt update && apt upgrade`
3. Reboot your computer so the kernel and libs that were just upgraded will be active for the rest of the steps
4. Log back into your computer and perform the guide's steps as written.

I believe this will give you an upgraded system and the steps in the guide will give you the real-time kernel you're trying for.